# Easiest way to create a polygon from an unmarked municipality (using QGIS)

Tags: qgis, polygon

Is there any easier way to create a polygon from the white empty space in: https://ibb.co/JF0Mnpx? This space is associated with a municipality but the best i can do is this: 
https://ibb.co/fxJYLBn using the add polygon feature in QGIS, which as you can see is not great. Is there an easier way to completely cover this blank area and assign information to it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with QGIS pretty easily. Just create a new Shape around that desired municipality. Then use the function "symmetric difference" with your new Shape and your other municipalities as input layers. The Funtion will give you a new Shape at your "white space"